# recreate editform.aspx with contentype-dropdown

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, custom-form, form

I've created a list with more than 80 fields. To lay it out more clearly I grouped the fields in multiple contenttypes. As soon as there was more than one contenttype Sharepoint showed a dropdown-box on top of the editform where my users could switch between fieldcategories.

When I accidentally deleted my *editform.aspx* I remained calm because I knew I could recreate it using SharePoint-Designer. Altough recreating the editform.aspx worked, the result is almost unusable. There is no more contenttype-dropdown and the fields are unsorted. When I add a new field to the list the editform doesn't get updated.

The only option I can see at the moment is to rebuild the list from scratch... which would take days. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to navigate through Site Settings -> Site Collection Administration -> Recycle Bin and check if you can see the deleted list there. If you could see it then you can use the option to restore the list.

Comment: thx, i've already looked for that file in the Recycle Bin - but bad luck - it's not there